# Property text not found on object of type UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
cell.lbl.text=[arry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

On this line it shows an error at `.text` which says:

> property text not found on object of type UIView

Comment: I suspect you need to cast lbl to type UILabel but we need to see more of your code to be sure. Please show us how cell and lbl are defined.

Comment: i have created a class for cells TableViewCell in that label is declared interface TableViewCell : UITableViewCell
property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *lbl;
@AliBeadle

Comment: Are you sure "lbl" is a UILabel and not a UIView?

Comment: it was in uiview that was the mistake thanks @RemyCilia